# Window snapping in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: 14.04, compiz, mate, snap-windows

I know how to enable window snapping in MATE Desktop, and it works. My problem is this. By default, Window A fills half the screen, and Window B fills half the screen, and you can't click and drag the edges of the window to resize without unsnapping the window, and resizing the left side, right side, top, and bottom. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I can replicate this, and will make a video on Monday.

Comment: I got it to sorta work for the first time ever, but only on the right side frame, the left window I couldnt get to work. Does this video replicate your issue? http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/out.ogv
if it does, please include it into your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Marco as your window manager, try switching to Compiz (System > Preference > Look and Feel > MATE Tweak). You can enable window snapping in CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and enable Compiz.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends compiz compiz-core compiz-mate compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default compizconfig-settings-manager
```

You should now have newer version of MATE Tweak and my modified build of Compiz installed.

Reboot (yes an actual reboot)

PRO TIP! Install guake or tilda and make sure it is running before you try switching window managers with MATE Tweak. If Compiz switching dies horribly you can pull-down guake or tilda using their respective key-binding and then run marco --replace which will get your window manager back.

Switching between Marco and Compiz
After the reboot, log in and open System -> Preferences -> MATE Tweak, choose Windows and then use the Window manager drop down to switch between Marco and Compiz. As soon as you select a window manager it will be replaced and MATE Tweak will close.

You can check which window manager you are using by running the following in a terminal.

wmctrl -m

For more information read [this](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-test-compiz-on-ubuntu-mate-14-04-and-14-10/182)

This can be tricky, so I recommend you try these steps on a VM before doing on your actual system.

Comment: Whenever possible, please try to summarize the relevant content of external links. Otherwise, if that link goes dark, your answer won't be nearly as useful.

Answer (score 0):

16.04 and 16.10 MATE you can do this:

**system > preferences > personal > onboard settings**

then click **window** from the left side menu

Then uncheck **dock to edge of screen**

You may want to figure out how to get Ubuntu to remember per application window preferences - that's next on my list, so every window opens in the same place, every time until I change it, that'd be great.

Answer (score -2):

I know this only from Unity but there must be a way to enable corner snapping in MATE.

1. Enable Corner Snapping.

   Top and bottom screen scaling do not work in a half-screen snap.
2. Grab window and throw it in a corner

   By dragging the window by its menu you can enlarge it to a quarter of the screen. Very useful in many cases.
3. Enlarge the window as much as needed, horizontally AND vertically!

   If you want to cover two thirds of the screen, go for it. If you want to fit that sheet of paper in true size, go for it. Fit the window to your preferred size and shape, and enjoy.
4. Optional: Grab it again and bring it down a bit

   If you don't want your window to sit in the corner, grab it and bring it down. It will retain the size and shape you just made. The window should snap to the side of the screen so you don't have to be too finnicky.

Sadly, this is Unity I'm talking about. But I hope this helps your workflow.