# How do I enable window snapping in Ubuntu 16.04 Mate?

Tags: 16.04, window, mate

In the Cinnamon desktop, `Super`+`left`, for example, will snap the active window to the left side of the screen.  Can the same behavior be enabled in Mate on Ubuntu 16.04?

From searching, all I can find are results about Package Snaps and this [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550475/window-snapping-in-ubuntu-mate) that begins

> I know how to enable window snapping in MATE Desktop, and it works. My
> problem is...

so evidently everyone knows this but me :)

Answer (score 3):

I tested this on CentOS 7 with Mate 1.16.2, but it should work similarly on Ubuntu.

### Enabling snapping by dragging windows with your mouse:

Open the "Windows" control panel under System - Preferences - Look and Feel - Windows. Go to the tab "Placement" and check **Enable side by side tiling**.

### Enabling snapping with keyboard shortcuts:

Open the "Keyboard Shortcuts" control panel under System - Preferences - Hardware - Keyboard Shortcuts. Assign the following keys (although there might be more of interest, depends on your personal preferences). I'm using the keybinds I'm familiar with from Windows 7/10 here, which uses the "Windows" key in combination with an arrow key (instead of `Super` the configuration screen might show `Mod4` or similar):

Maximize Window - <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
Restore Window - <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>
Tile window to the east (right) side of the screen - <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>
Tile window to the west (left) side of the screen - <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>

Comment: This works perfectly in Mint 20.1 / MATE.

Answer (score 0):

- Drag the Window to the screen sides, or
- Use `Ctrl + Alt + NumPad#` to move the window accordingly:

  - `NumPad4 / NumPadLeft` for left side,
  - `NumPad6 / NumPadRight` for right side,
  - `NumPad9 / NumPadPageUp` for upper right corner,
  - etc..

Comment: Doesn't work on this laptop, where I have no numpad but I have Fn+U for 4, e.g. Fn+U successfully moves my cursor left, but Ctrl+Alt+Fn+U doesn't make my window left-side half-screen. Windows snapping is enabled, OS is NixOS, so I'm not sure if maybe they defined things differently. It does have the "draw window to far left and it'll resize to half-screen" though, so it's not half bad.